# How to use 'choice_name' in Symfony?

Tags: symfony

I have a checkbox list with Cyrillic names. It generates

```
<input type="checkbox" id="region_form_name_22" name="region_form[name][]" value="22">"
```

I want to get in `$query = $request->query->get("region_form");` a string value (as "Алтайская область".

I try to use ['choice_name'](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)
but I got an error

`"The name "Алтайский край" contains illegal characters. Names should start with a letter, digit or underscore and only contain letters, digits, numbers, underscores ("_"), hyphens ("-") and colons (":")."`

```
$builder->add('name', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Region::class,
            'choice_label' => 'name_with_type',
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
                    ->orderBy('u.name_with_type', 'ASC');
            },
           'choice_name' => function ($entity) {
               return $entity->getNameWithType();
           },
            'multiple' => true,
            'expanded' => true,
        ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Найти'))
        ;
```

How to get not "id" in query, but "name"?

Comment: Do I understand you right, that you have a field, which lets user choose a `Region`, and you want to get **name** of selected `Region`?

Comment: Yes i want get "name" of selected checkbox. Not `id` but name. To get in `$query = $request->query->get("region_form");` - array of ['Алтайский край', 'Бурятия'.

Comment: You shouldn't get form data directly from request. Use your form again, to validate request data and then get data from the form. This way you should get `Region` object from this field.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#processing-forms

Comment: I need it for a search form. When i checked a "Алтайский край" checkbox, a controller get a query  `$query = $request->query->get("region_form");
        $clinics = $clinicRepository->findByRegionField($query);` and run createQueryBuilder it the repository.